# React.js How to pass data from Parent Component to Child Component

Tags: reactjs, reactive-programming, react-props, react-component, pass-data

I'm trying to make an API request by Search and by ID and want to pass that id to another component which will show the ID data in another page when button is clicked, but I am not able to pass that data to another component, please can someone help me with this I'm trying to learn React and have researched a lot but couldn't figure out the solution. Passing data from parent to child and vice versa is confusing me. any help would really be appreciated.

Parent Component

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import ProductDetailPage from "./productdetailpage";

class ProductLists extends React.Component {
  state = {
    movies: [],
    name: "",
    para: "No Data"
  };

  onchange = event => {
    this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
  };

  onsubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const nameValue = this.state.name;
    axios
      .get(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=bcfe7e46&s=${nameValue}`)
      .then(res => {
        const movies = res.data.Search;
        this.setState({ movies });
      });
  };

  viewDetail = id => {
    axios.get(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=bcfe7e46&i=${id}`).then(res => {
      const movieId = res.data;

      //below i'm trying to pass the movieId into other component
      const moviedata = <ProductDetailPage passMovieId={movieId} />;
      console.log(moviedata.props);
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onsubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search Movie"
            onChange={this.onchange}
          />
        </form>
        {this.state.name === "" ? (
          <h1>No Data</h1>
        ) : (
          <ul>
            {this.state.movies.map(movie => (
              <li key={movie.imdbID}>
                <img alt="img" src={movie.Poster} />
                <h1>{movie.Title}</h1>
                <p>{movie.Year}</p>
                <button onClick={() => this.viewDetail(movie.imdbID)}>
                  <Link to="./productdetail">View More</Link>
                </button>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default ProductLists;
```

Child Component

```
import React from "react";

class ProductDetailPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        <li>
          <img alt="img" src={this.props.movieId.Poster} />
          <h1>{this.props.movieId.Title}</h1>
          <p>{this.props.movieId.Plot}</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default ProductDetailPage;
```

Comment: What is the error/message you are getting in child component?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the id in the Link and move the viewDetail Function there:

```
    <Link movieId={movie.imdbID} to="./productdetail">View More</Link>
```

then it should accessible as a prop in that component:

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link/others